# Can't install and run Tor Browser in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, 22.04, system, tor-browser

[I downloaded Tor Browser from the command line but when I try to open it, it prompts this error from the SO. Can anyone figured out what kind of error it is?? Do you guys think it is a bug from the system? or it might be related to the Tor itself??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcSPf.png)

Comment: Is your system fully upgraded?  What is the actual error message, as I don't understand what you mean by "*it prompts this error from the SO*".  FYI:  The Tor project update the package very often, on rare occasion those changes do require a Ubuntu *Core-Dev/MOTU* to re-package the Ubuntu package; which does require someone to notice it; report the issue & 1-3 days for that fix to be done. I don't see any actual error message in your question though that is understandable, at least to me.

Comment: Try to update and upgrade your kernel: **sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade**.
after that you could try to just install the debian package from the tor website: https://www.torproject.org/download/